# Enable to display OpenLayers maps correctly in REACT JS app

Tags: openlayers, react

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Map, View } from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import 'ol/ol.css';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 0,
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        new Map({
          target: "map-container",
            layers: [
                new TileLayer({
                    source: new OSM(),
                }),
            ],
            view: new View({
                center: [0, 0],
                zoom: 0,
            }),
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div style={{height:'60vh',width:'100%'}} id="map-container" className="map-container" />
        );
    }}
```

The result :
[image]

The problem is that I don't know what I get ' Two maps ' instead of one map. The code should only display one map. I'm new to React JS.

Answer (score 3):

When the React component is unmounted. This prevents multiple maps being added to the map container on a re-render., so you need to set the map target to "undefined", or/ an empty string to represent a nonexistent HTML element ID. This prevents multiple maps being added to the map container on a re-render.

Comment: It works for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Add a `this.map` for the `new Map` in `componentDidMount`. Then add `componentWillUnmount() { this.map.setTarget(undefined); }`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a state variable and check if the map already exists to prevent it from being re-rendered

```
import React from 'react';
import { Map, View } from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import 'ol/ol.css';

export default class Mapa extends React.Component {
        
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 0,
          myMap: new Map({
                            target: "",
                              layers: [
                                  new TileLayer({
                                      source: new OSM(),
                                  }),
                              ],
                              view: new View({
                                  center: [0, 0],
                                  zoom: 0,
                              })
                        })
        };
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        
        this.state.myMap.setTarget("map-container");
       
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{height:'500px',width:'500px'}} id="map-container" className="map-container" />
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the export file of react, if it is mounted in App, if you use react.StrictMode. Will perform two renderings。

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App'
import './index.css'

 ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as 
 HTMLElement).render(
 <React.StrictMode>
 <App />
 </React.StrictMode>
 )
```

Now you can render normally without using React.StrictMode.

> It is expected that setState updaters will run twice in strict mode in development. This helps ensure the code doesn’t rely on them running a single time (which wouldn’t be the case if an async render was aborted and alter restarted). If your setState updaters are pure functions (as they should be) then this shouldn’t affect the logic of your application.

Answer (score 0):

**This is how you can implement OpenLayers with React / Nextjs**

```
import { Attribution, defaults, FullScreen, Rotate, ScaleLine,} from "ol/control"
import Map from "ol/Map"
import View from "ol/View"

const mapTargetElement = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
const [map, setMap] = useState<Map>()

 useEffect(() => {
        // Create OpenLayers map so we can display it to the user.
        const InitializeMap = new Map({
            // The collection of layers associated with this map.
            layers: [],
            /* The map's view allows to specify the center,
             * zoom, resolution, and rotation of the map.
             */
            view: new View({
                // The map view projection.
                projection: WEB_MERCATOR_COORDINATE_SYSTEM_ID, // "EPSG:3857"
                center: [0, 0],
                zoom: 0,
                minZoom: 0,
                maxZoom: 28,
            }),
            /* The map's default controls is a visible widget with a DOM
             * element in a fixed position on the map.
             */
            controls: defaults({ attribution: false }).extend([
                new Attribution({
                    collapsed: true,
                    collapsible: true,
                }),
                // Add a fullscreen button control to the map.
                new FullScreen(),
                // Add scale line control to the map.
                new ScaleLine(),
                // Add a reset rotation button control to the map.
                new Rotate(),
            ]),
        })

        // Set the Initialized map to the map target element.
        InitializeMap.setTarget(mapTargetElement.current || "")
        // Set the current map, so we can continue working with it.
        setMap(InitializeMap)

        /* We set map target to "undefined", an empty string to represent a
         * nonexistent HTML element ID, when the React component is unmounted.
         * This prevents multiple maps being added to the map container on a
         * re-render.
         */
        return () => InitializeMap.setTarget("")
    }, [])


    return (
        <div
            ref={mapTargetElement}
            className="map"
            style={{
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
                position: "relative",
            }}
        ></div>
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problem and I fixed removing <React.StrictMode> from index.tsx file